# How many 2D planes are there in a finite 3D object?

Tags: mass, geometry, volume

More specifically: How many 2d planes (of any area) can fit in a finite 3d object?

I believe the answer is infinity, but this leads to another question:
How much mass does a 2d object have? Zero, right? But zero * infinity = zero.

So is the answer to the original question undefined?

Comment: You have just discovered something you should remember for the rest of your life, which is that $0\times\infty$ does not have a well defined value and can be different things in different contexts

Answer (score 2):

Infinity is not a number. However, there are certain numbers that can be used to describe things that are infinite, such as [beth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number).

If by 2D planes in a 3D object, you mean 2-dimensional affine subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$, then there are $\beth_1$ 2D planes in any 3D object.

Matter is generally thought to be composed of 0-dimensional point particles, but classical mechanics models matter by both point particles and continuous mass distributions, which can be 1-, 2-, or 3-dimensional. Thus, a physical object could be modelled as a 2D object with non-zero mass.

Also, as noted in the comments, $0 \cdot \infty$ is an indeterminate form without a well defined value. For the case of mass continuously distributed over a 3-dimensional region, any 2D plane will contain zero mass, yet combination of all of those 2D planes does contain non-zero mass. This is because ordinary summation only works for countable sets, whereas you need an integral to add up uncountably many terms.